# Placing App::Import on CakePHP2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, import, location, cakephp-2.0

I was wondering where is the correct location to place the App::import on CakePHP2.

I was thinking that it should be better to use it in each function in order not to load if another function doesnt use it.

Something like this:

```
public function name(){
   App::import('Controller', 'Classifiers');
   $classifiersController = new ClassifiersController();
   $this->request->data['Post'] = $classifiersController->getIdCategory('hola');
}
```

Instead of using the import at the top of the class.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct place for app::import: no where! ;)

you use App::uses() in 2.0 for all app classes (import is only for vendor stuff).
and you would place it at the very top of your file (after the `<?php`)

in your case:

```
<?php
App::uses('ClassifiersController', 'Controller');

...

public function name(){
    $classifiersController = new ClassifiersController();
    $this->request->data['Post'] = $classifiersController->getIdCategory('hola');
}
```

although I HIGHLY recommend to take a closer look at what you are doing there.
using another controller in a controller is pretty wrong - in your case you would probably want to import a model and use its method. controllers are only for logic of a specific request action. place all other things in the model (fat model, slim controller principle).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can i ask why should we use it at the very start and not when we use it? Wouldn't we be importing stuff that we might not use if we don't call that function?
Thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe App::uses() doesn't actually import a file. It adds the file to a list of files you might use and only imports it at the time you actually reference it (lazy load).

Comment: exactly. you just "declare" those files. lazy loading then loads them as soon as necessary - and automatically. that is why you can put them at the very top.